# Android: Is there any way to turn on-off the physical keyboard programmatically?

Tags: android, keyboard, usb, host

I have an android 3.1 with usb host capabilities. I connected to it via usb an RFID reader that works as a keyboard emulator. For keyboard emulator I mean that once I scan a tag it sends the output as keystrokes.

Now once this reader is plugged in there is no way to have the soft keyboard visible. So it's impossible to type anything else than the rfid codes.

I have tried without success the examples to "force show soft keyboard": they work until I plug in the RFID reader. Then the soft keyboard disappears no matter what!!!

My software will work on "kiosk mode", that's why I ask about doing this process programmatically. This is not a matter of usability.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the hardware keyboard (as the title states) or show the software keyboard (as your question states)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you got any editText or similar to get the focus this way?

```
someEditText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getActivity(). 
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);                 
mgr.showSoftInput(someEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I mean, if you do this after plugging your RFID reader, the keyboard should appear. Did you try this?

Comment: This question is now useless because there is an "on/off" switch on android 3.1+