# How to turn on-off the physical keyboard programmatically?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Everytime I plug a keyboard or scanner, the soft keyboard no longer shows when EditText is in focus.

I've already tried to force the soft keyboard to always show using the inputManager, but it only works when the physical keyboard is unplugged.

```
 inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
 inputManager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(textView.getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

I'm using API 12 - Android 3.1.

I couldn't also find how to show the window pop-up where the user can manually turn off the physical keyboard.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: I don't think you can show the soft keyboard if a hardware keyboard is plugged in. I think they did it that way so that when you plug in a keyboard you are guaranteed to get to use the full screen for whatever you are looking at.

Comment: thanks Tim. Android allows the user to manually turn off the physical keyboard can be turned off when the user clicks on the keyboard icon at the status bar.  Even it the physical keyboard is turned off, he can still types on it, but then soft keyboard will show as well. I need the soft keyboard to be shown all the time.

Comment: Nice find. That knowledge will definitely come in handy =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Is there any way to turn on-off the physical keyboard programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435295/android-is-there-any-way-to-turn-on-off-the-physical-keyboard-programmatically)