# Can I programmatically disable/enable the physical keyboard?

Tags: android, android-hardware, android-settings, android-hardware-keyboard

I want to enable the soft keyboard when a scanner is plugged into the device. In order to do this I need to disable the hardware keyboard
Is there a way to disable/enable the use of hardware keyboard in Android 3.0+ programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable physical keyboard in code(use virtual keyboard all the time)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143805/how-to-disable-physical-keyboard-in-codeuse-virtual-keyboard-all-the-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Is there any way to turn on-off the physical keyboard programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435295/android-is-there-any-way-to-turn-on-off-the-physical-keyboard-programmatically)